# LESS inverse function of e()

Tags: css, less

So I just tried using LESS today. Based on examples available in official website, I've managed to script my CSS like below. But there's single line that not work like I want, which I want to convert color type variable to string (wrapped with single quotes).

I have color variable, for example:

```
@colorA: #f7fcff;
@colorB: #f2faff;
```

I want to convert them to string, so I can use in filter CSS e.g.:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='@colorA', endColorstr='@colorB', GradientType=0 );
```

But that not work. So, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [string interpolation syntax](https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j/wiki/Less-Language-String-Interpolation) there like `@{}`

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( 
        startColorstr='@{colorA}', endColorstr='@{colorB}', 
        GradientType=0 );
```

**Compiled**:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(
        startColorstr='#f7fcff', endColorstr='#f2faff', 
        GradientType=0);
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! :) Will approved few minutes later